# Some troubles with Graphics in CodenameOne on iOS

Tags: ios, graphics, codenameone

In my project, there were some differences between work on Android and iOS. includeNativeBool is false.

For Example:
[image]

Code for this:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    x = getX();
    y = getY();
    w = getWidth();
    h = getHeight();
    r1 = w/20;
    r2 = r1/2;
    d1 = r1*2;
    d2 = r2*2;

    // Fill background
    g.setColor(getStyle().getFgColor());
    g.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
}

public void FirstPart(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(getStyle().getBgColor());
    // North-West
    g.fillArc(x-r1, y-r1, d1, d1, 270, 360);
    // North
    g.fillArc(x+w/2-r1, y-r1, d1, d1, 180, 360);
    // North-East
    g.fillArc(x+w-r1, y-r1, d1, d1, 90, 180);
}

public void MiddlePartBegin(Graphics g) {        
    g.setColor(getStyle().getBgColor());
    // North-West
    g.fillArc(x-r2, y-r2, d2, d2, 270, 360);
    // North-East
    g.fillArc(x+w-r2, y-r2, d2, d2, 90, 180);        
} 

public void MiddlePartEnd(Graphics g) {
    if (dash != null) {
        int c = w/iW + (w % iW > 0 ? 1 : 0); // Ceil
        for (int i=0;i<c;i++) {
            g.drawImage(dash, i*iW+x, y+h-1);
        }
    }

    g.setColor(getStyle().getBgColor());
    // South-West
    g.fillArc(x-r2, y+h-r2, d2, d2, 270, 360);
    // South-East
    g.fillArc(x+w-r2, y+h-r2, d2, d2, 270, 360);
} 

public void LastPart(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(getStyle().getBgColor());
    // South-West
    g.fillArc(x-r1, y+h-r1, d1, d1, 270, 360);
    // South-East
    g.fillArc(x+w-r1, y+h-r1, d1, d1, 270, 360);
}
```

Or this:

[image]

As Image I'm used the URLImage class. Here is my Adapter code:

```
public static final URLImage.ImageAdapter ToCircle = new URLImage.ImageAdapter() {

    int borderWidth = 6;

    public EncodedImage adaptImage(EncodedImage downloadedImage, EncodedImage placeholderImage) {
        Image originalImage;

        // Crop and resize
        int w = downloadedImage.getWidth();
        int h = downloadedImage.getHeight();
        if (w > h) {
            originalImage = downloadedImage.subImage(
                (w-h)/2, 0, 
                h, h, 
                true
            );
        } else {
            originalImage = downloadedImage.subImage(
                0, (h-w)/2, 
                w, w, 
                true
            );
        }


        int pS = Math.min(placeholderImage.getHeight(), placeholderImage.getWidth());
        originalImage = originalImage.scaledHeight(pS);


        w = originalImage.getWidth();
        h = originalImage.getHeight();
        Log.p(Integer.toString(w)+";"+Integer.toString(h));
        Image finalImage = Image.createImage(w+2*borderWidth, h+2*borderWidth);

        Image maskedImage = originalImage.applyMask(
            createCircleMask(w,h)
        );

        Graphics g  = finalImage.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(0xff3d00);
        g.fillRect(
                0, 0, 
                finalImage.getWidth(), finalImage.getHeight() 
               // 0, 360
        );
        g.drawImage(maskedImage, borderWidth, borderWidth);

        w = finalImage.getWidth();
        h = finalImage.getHeight();

        return EncodedImage.createFromImage(
            finalImage.applyMask(
                createCircleMask(w,h)
            ),
            false
        );
    }

    public Object createCircleMask(int w, int h) {
        Image maskImage = Image.createImage(w, h);
        Graphics g = maskImage.getGraphics();
        g.setAntiAliased(true);
        g.setColor(0x000000);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g.setColor(0xffffff);
        g.fillArc(0, 0, w, h, 0, 360);
        return maskImage.createMask();
    }

    public boolean isAsyncAdapter() {
        return false;
    }
};
```

In the last trouble Images maybe don't resized to plasehoder Image size...

Also I'm noticed that elements with transparency are displayed as  transparent with value 0xFF

Answer (score 1):

The missing padding on the top are due to the `includeNativeBool=false` since iOS draws under the status bar area.

For the masking see if this helps:

```
    originalImage = originalImage.scaledHeight(pS);

    // then add this
    originalImage = EncodedImage.createFromImage(originalImage, false);
```

About the arcs not appearing, its hard to tell how you applied that code to the UI. I'm assuming you didn't use something consistent like a glasspane?

Since a component can trigger its own repaint some custom painting code might not occur in the right order.

Comment: Well. Arcs I fixed by filling full circle - g.fillArc(x, y, d2, d2, 0, 360). But trouble with EncodedImage wasn't solve. As well as with the alpha-transparents. As this code works fine in Android, so troubles are definitely in iOS implementation.

Comment: "includeNativeBool=false" brokes a lot of things in the project. How can I define this padding independently?

Comment: If you want includeNativeBool=false you can define paintsTitleBarBool=true and define padding for the StatusBar UIID. The native iOS theme defines the padding on the top implicitly. I'm unclear about which alpha transparencies you are referring to? The problem I see with the image masking seems to be a result of a badly placed mask, its just hard to see how that can happen... Since the masking code clearly works, its weird that it fails in the first usage... Can you extract a test case for this and submit it? https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/

Comment: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1419
Here issue with this trouble

Comment: About masking. I think that function originalImage.scaledHeight(pS); doesn't work on iOS.

Comment: The implementation differs between iOS and Android. In iOS it just returns an image that has specific markings indicating the new size without physically resizing the image. I'm guessing that this creates an edge case that fails for your case but I'm not sure which piece conflicts... The alpha issue is something that existed in the old pipeline, I thought it was fixed in the new one but apparently it was missed.

Comment: So. Is there any way to fix trouble with image sizes? May be it's occurs because in URLImage Adapters used EncodedImage.getInternal() method? I can't extend URLImage for tests because constructor in private access. Everything else, not convenient for use RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL method with images with transparency (png, gif images).

Comment: Can you isolate a test case and file it in our github issue tracker? I can make guesses but its a bit hard to track these things without a test case.